# When I use the data-navmenu in flexdashboard, the pages are opened under each other

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I have 16 pages in my shiny app flexdashboard and It doesn't seem so good in the navigation bar if I want to show all of them, so I try using {data-navmenu=""} I separate my pages into 2 groups "Conventional Models" and Fuzzy Models like this:

```
   Modelfuzzy_Guotanaka{data-navmenu="Fuzzy Models"}
================================

modelfuzzy_kaoliu{data-navmenu="Fuzzy Models"}
================================

modelfuzzy_Possibilistic{data-navmenu="Fuzzy Models"} 
================================

model_Additive{data-navmenu="Conventional Models"}  
================================

model_Addmin{data-navmenu="Conventional Models"}  
================================
```

The problem is When I click on the first page, it opens in a new tab, and when I then click on the second page, it opens in the same tab (under the previous opened page) instead of opening in a new tab as a separate page, what should I do?